# Send bytes data to UDP server via NGINX

Tags: nginx, udp

For now, I'm just a beginner with Nginx.

I have scoured a lot of information on the net trying to send data to my UDP server, but it all failed.

So please help me with that and share with me your code. **Thank you!**

Comment: you should go through the [Nginx documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/)

Comment: @ShivamUttam Can you send me something more detailed?

Comment: just search regarding UDP load balancer ..there you can find what you are looking for

Comment: @ShivamUttam anything else?